After function is finished;wait till action
I have a function that outputs some data from a endpoint
var test = async function()
{
    const result = await getData();
    getUserInputContinue();
}

After that, I will continue with more code after the user pressed any key. I want to do that with inquirer.
async function getUserInputContinue() {
    console.log("WAIT USER INPUT");
    const questions = [
        {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'CONTINUE',
            message: chalk.green('Press Enter to continue')
        }
    ];
    return inquirer.prompt(questions);
}

But I tried a lot of things, but I can't hold the code until there is a respons from getData().
How can I archive that?

Are you saying that the code does not wait on getData() being ready? In that case the issue is inside your getData function.

It should wait untill I get a return from getData()? Or not? It is always outputted before the return..

This is literally not possible. getData() does return first. If you disagree, provide evidence. But as I said earlier, the problem probably lies in getData() and a misunderstanding of how asynchrononous processes work.
